# Create a "dynamic" menu with Azure Chatbot

Tags: node.js, azure, dynamic, menu, chatbot

I am currently working with the MS chatbot on Azure, using **node.js**
I am at a point where I need to display a menu for the user, about different choices that may change from time to time.

I get the values through an API call and put them in a tab, then I create the menu and send it to the user. The problem is : I can't create a **dynamic** menu from my array

This is what I tried :

```
menu_choices = [x,y,z]
var menu = new builder.Message(session)
                        .text("This is the menu")
                        .suggestedActions(
                        builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                                session, [ function(){
                                        menu_choices.forEach(function(choice){
                                             builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "I want to select " + choice, choice)                                                
                                        })}
                                    ]));            
        session.send(menu);
```

It looks strange to use a function inside the SuggestedActions but I don't see how I can solve this, or even if it is possible or not.

Thanks and have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with the Microsoft support, we found the way (well mainly they haha) to do it :

```
array_Menu = [choice1,choice2,choice3]
var menu = new builder.Message(This is the menu :")
                        .suggestedActions(
                        builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                                session, 
                                array_Menu.map(function(choice) {
                                    return builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "This is a choice : " + choice, choice)
                                }
                    )
                )
            );          
        session.send(menu);
```